# C++: How to add a library in Netbeans (DarkGDK + DirectX SDK)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, netbeans, include

I'm trying to learn how to make games with DarkGDK. But I have to write in Visual Studio.
I don't like Visual Studio. Its suggestions (`Ctrl-Space` for Completion) are bad (in my opinion) and the compiler is broken (See my previous questions).

So I want to migrate to Netbeans, with MSys and MinGW. But I'm not able to use the DarkGDK
library in Netbeans. I added two include folders:

- C:\Program Files\The Game Creators\Dark GDK\Include
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2007)\Include

After adding this include directories, I can `#include <DarkGDK.h>`.
But he shows a warning: "`There are unresolved includes inside <DarkGDK.h>`"

And when I try to compile: `main.cpp:9:21: warning: DarkGDK.h: No such file or directory`

In Visual Studio are `Include files` and `Library files`. And in Netbeans, there is only `Include Directories` when I go to Tools -> Options -> C/C++ -> Code Assistance.

So, my question is: "How can I add the Library files in Netbeans"?
Or does any-one did this yet and knows how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I found the include directories in Tools -> Options don't work.  You need to right click on your project and go to properties -> C++ Compiler and add your include directories.   Then from properties -> Linker to add your library directories and libraries.

Comment: Thanks for aswering, but it seems unpossible to use DarkGDK in another IDE.